# Regex Match for first line of Powershell Error Output

Tags: regex, powershell

I am using new-pssession to connect to machines and am storing any errors in a value specified by the -errorVariable paramater.  I want to call this variable later for output but on want to show the the first line, minus the comp name in brackets.

Heres an example of what i get.

```
New-PSSession : [ABCGFAXYZUT579] Connecting to remote server ABCGFAXYZUT579 failed with the 
following error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the 
specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a 
firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this 
computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote 
computers within the same local subnet. For more information, see the
about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-PSSession -ComputerName ABCGFAXYZUT579 -ErrorVariable errors912  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New- 
PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WinRMOperationTimeout,PSSessionOpenFailed
```

I have tried passing the variable to select-string to get only what i need but everything i have tried still gives me this

```
[ABCGFAXYZUT579] Connecting to remote server ABCGFAXYZUT579 failed with the following error 
message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name 
is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for 
the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the 
WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same 
local subnet. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

I have also tried splitting it into seperate lines like this
`($errors912 -split '\r?\n' -ne '')`  and piping to select-string but i still get the above returned.

is there an easy way to get everything after the first white space and before the first period? leaving this?

```
Connecting to remote server ABCGFAXYZUT579 failed with the following error 
message : WinRM cannot complete the operation.
```

Comment: Try with `(?<= )[A-Z][^.]+.`

Comment: Have you examined the other properties of the error object to get just the error message? (Are you really sure you need a regex?)

Comment: @ctwheels that one didnt work.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart, I can get the exception property, or errordetails property from it, but still that gives me the second block i posted above. I just want the first sentence of that so i dont know of any other way to do it.  Even when using the tostring() method on either property i havent found a regex  that works.

Comment: @Keets [see it working here](https://tio.run/##dVFLS8NAEL77K@YgVLENXkQsFmkLeqqI9dkQYbKZbQY3u2F329hfH3cbUvXgdeZ7ztSmIetKUqptjytyDtcEExjcUzN6WC7DgI2GMaTT2fzudvr2vnp@uri8ymButCbhWa/BG7BUGU/gyG7Jwl8sSGRFBTTsS/AlgTRKmSYyyVpjobcdwyvrxwUI1Np4EKaqFQXVyDE1WfQhSwIvZFnuwhT9fuVqEiw5OETGxocAGisCdrBFxcXwB3oAhB0KEdvlKojH0HGvyTfGfg4BddGxECRbalApoC9BdYwQCnTwLm4szWLvRxrzWDXSMZbsbUBaUwVOwPQZEpjtoCCJG@WHv@T@8as3uWIBtTUyXNOB4or9Qf7nBb2829@bdXeieA9lBCpwmzy0TAZHh2@PKvSihMHJzfUETtPpaJWlH0l2FjGLuCKXnmdt@w0) (had to shorten the content so that the URL fit in my comment, but you can just copy/paste your original text)

Comment: @ctwheels ya maybe it was when i using select-string instead of -match, only problem is all that returns when i run that, is true. I dont get the string returned also

Comment: @Keets `match` uses a special variable `$Matches` - the link I provided shows this.

Comment: @ctwheels sorry im drunk, i see that now. Works when its just one error but seems to grab everything again when errors are returned for multiple machines

Comment: @Keets are you using `$Matches[0]`? I'm getting just `Connecting to remote server ABCGFAXYZUT579 failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation.` as output. Not sure what you mean, can you clarify?

Comment: `[string]$errors912 -replace "^(\[.*?\] )|(?<=\.).*"` however I'm _not_ a regex expert…

Comment: @CtWheels ya what you gave works perfect.  For one error though.  when i tried it with multiples errors stored in the variable, from mutiple failed machines. The Matches[0] Variable just returns the first line which is just the error for one machine.  Cant post example in the small reply box.

Comment: @JosefZ your expert advice worked.  Running that will return the first line from each error.  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$NewSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName ABCGFAXYZUT579 -ErrorVariable errors912 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ( $errors912.Count -gt 0 ) {
    [string]$errors912 -replace "^(\[.*?\] )|(?<=\.).*"
}
```

> ```
> Connecting to remote server ABCGFAXYZUT579 failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request.
> ```

The `$errors912.Count -gt 0` condition is equivalent to `$null -eq $NewSession`.

Please go to some on-line regex tester/debugger e.g. https://regex101.com/ for the regex explanation.